# Personalize "Radio" button in a HTML from

Tags: html, css, forms

Well, I can change the size of "Radio" using CSS but **I** **cant** **quit the border and change the background color**.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="radio" class="textColoPgE1" id="textColoPgE" name="textColoPgE" value="col1">
```

And the CSS:

```
.textColoPgE1
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
}
```

How to personalize my "Radio" buttons? I hope you have a solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a fake radio button and hide the (browser) default one to make it work. See the example below. First it's a blue button, but after it's been clicked (and checked), it's red.

The `label:before` will be the container where your fake radio button will show up.

```css
/* Hide the radio button */

input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}

/* We style the label */

.textColoPgE1-label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.textColoPgE1-label:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* We style the checked item */

.textColoPgE1:checked + .textColoPgE1-label:before {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="textColoPgE1" id="textColoPgE" name="textColoPgE" value="col1">
<label for="textColoPgE" class="textColoPgE1-label">Radio button</label>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check this in a few minutes

Comment: To clarify: What you do is to hide the real radio button (`display:none`), and replace it with a `<label>` which you can style easily. Clicking on the `<label>`-element is the same as clicking on the actual radio-button.

Comment: Yes, as I said in the first sentence of my answer. The functionality does not get broken and it's a widely supported solution for this (common) problem.

Comment: Thank you, But i have like 10 buttons (user chose a colors) so I cant use the .input to determinate wich elemt is affected, I dont want all the buttoms with same color, so how can I make it more selective? Thankyou

Comment: I edited the code snippet to just use the class `.textColoPgE1` like you provided. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have here a great example of what you need to do to make your own radio button style:

```
http: //codepen.io/mitchmc/pen/pebIx
```

Basically, you need to turn of the button and style the label.
I searched for solutions for the same issue and found this very clear and helpful explanation: http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: Thank you I will check this

Comment: Let me know if that is what you're looking for or something else.